# Redshift - Get RemoteHost of Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have several servers who interact with a single redshift cluster under the same user and I'm attempting to distinguish which host is making which query. I tried looking at joining `stl_connection_log` and `stl_query` but their mutual parameter is only `PID` which is shared among all hosts.

Obviously I can give them each a user (probably should have happened before..) but I still need to get the historic data. Is this even possible?